# CSS color hover wrong

Tags: css, font-face, webfonts

i use Allegro fonts for top menu and got problem **when i hover on it the color not display full width in Chrome and Safari** :(
you can test on this link
http://preview.86solutions.com/fairpart

Comment: what error ? (*works fine for me..*)

Comment: are you sure? check carefully
HOVER ERROR

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong with your font I guess. 
When you add some more padding-right to the element it looks fine.

```
.menu a {
color: black;
padding-right: 20px;
}
```

see it yourself:
Add a border to the element and it will cut off on the right side.

Answer (score 0):

Looking okay in both chrome and IE.I don't know what version are you using now, I have checked this demo in chrome 19.0.1084.82 and IE8 and IE9.I have seen your code and everything looks good.

BUT, IE does not support the font-family inherit property.If you still have the problem you should modify your style.css like this :

```
                .menu a:hover,.menu a:active  {
                     font-family: "Allegro"; /* because IE doesn't suprort inherit */ 
                 text-decoration:none;
                  color:#c4c04d;
                      }
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: thanks for your info.
but problem is only Chrome and Safari :)
i think the most important problem is Allegro font is Intalic so it will out of the width of <li>.